# boost multi_index hashed_unique vs unordered_map lookup performance

Tags: boost, boost-multi-index, boost-unordered

Are the look-up performances for `boost::unordered_map`'s and  `boost::multi_index` containers (with a hashed unique index) the same. I imagine that in `boost::multi_index` containers you have to do two look-ups: firstly, in a table that represents the hashed index (and contains a pointer to the actual value associated with that key) and a second look-up due to the fact that you need to follow that pointer to get to your value. It seems that the `boost::unordered_map` implementation might avoid this second look-up (and therefore be faster).

Answer (score 2):

Lookup performance should be exactly the same --Boost.Multiindex internal structure does not involve extra indirections as you seem to assume. In any case, when in doubt profile and see by yourself.

Comment: In big O notation, what would it be?